# Kotlin the ui state of the checkbox won't change when pressed

Tags: kotlin

I've got a list of checkboxes, I need to make it so when one checkbox is pressed that it changes on the screen as well (which doesn't now). This is my code:

```
@Composable
fun SearchBarWithDropdown(
  options: Array<String>,
  optionsSelected: Array<Boolean>,
  dismissPopup: () -> Unit,
  onPress: () -> Unit,
  showDropdown: Boolean,
  onCheckedChange: (Int,Boolean) -> Unit
) {

 
  Column {
    SelectableTextField(
      textValue = "Friends",
      onClick = onPress
    )
    if (showDropdown) {
      Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        Popup(onDismissRequest = dismissPopup) {
          Surface(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            elevation = 8.dp,
          ) {
            LazyColumn(
              modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .heightIn(max = 200.dp)
            ) {
              itemsIndexed(options) { index, option ->
                Row(
                  modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                ){
                  Checkbox(
                    checked = optionsSelected[index],
                    onCheckedChange = { onCheckedChange(index,it) },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
                  )
                  Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxWidth()
                  ) {
                    Text(
                      text = option,
                      modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                      style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The **onCheckedChange** function just changes the value in the optionsSelected list (this works). So I don't understand why the checkbox won't get marked/unmarked when I press it.

Edit: when I dismiss the pop up and then press the SelectableTextField again, then it's updated correctly, though this is prolly because the checkboxes are regenerated again.

Comment: Using mutable objects such as Array<T> or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as Array or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List<T>> and the immutable listOf(). [Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)